# Eliminating Duplicate Rows after Modifying Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Our *Purchasing Department* wants me to modify our application so that *Requisition Requests* can be searched using **Part Numbers**.

Each *Requisition Request* will contain at least one part, but could contain several parts.

The *Stored Procedure* is set up so that fields may be populated or they may not be, so it pulls data based on what is passed in.

Here is how the *Stored Procedure* works before my modifications:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRequisitions](@status_id int, @startdate varchar(50), @enddate varchar(50),
  @Vendor_Name varchar(200), @PO_Number varchar(50), @Req_ID int, @datesearch bit, @Part_ID varchar(50)) AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  select
    a.Req_ID, a.Vendor_ID, a.Vendor_Name, a.Req_Date, a.PO_Number, a.Requested_Buy, a.approved,
    b.status,
    c.supervisor_login,
    case when d.req_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as HasDocs
  from Req as a
    join Status as b on (a.Status_ID=b.Status_ID)
    left outer join Supervisor as c on (a.Requested_Login=c.Emp_Login)
    left outer join req_doc as d on (a.Req_ID=d.req_id)
  where
    ((@datesearch is null or @datesearch=0) or (a.Req_Date between @startdate and @enddate))
    and ((@status_id is null or @status_id=0) or (a.Status_ID=@status_id))
    and ((@Vendor_Name is null or LEN(RTrim(@Vendor_Name))=0) or (a.Vendor_Name like '%'+@Vendor_Name+'%'))
    and ((@PO_Number is null or LEN(RTrim(@PO_Number))=0) or (a.PO_Number like @PO_Number+'%'))
    and ((@Req_ID is null or @Req_ID=0) or (a.Req_ID=@Req_ID))
END
```

To query this same *DataSet* using an optional *Part Number* `Part_ID` field, I added the following code that joins with the `Req_Part` *DataTable*:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRequisitions](@status_id int, @startdate varchar(50), @enddate varchar(50),
  @Vendor_Name varchar(200), @PO_Number varchar(50), @Req_ID int, @datesearch bit, @Part_ID varchar(50)) AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  select
    a.Req_ID, a.Vendor_ID, a.Vendor_Name, a.Req_Date, a.PO_Number, a.Requested_Buy, a.approved,
    b.status,
    c.supervisor_login,
    case when d.req_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as HasDocs
  from Req as a
    join Status as b on (a.Status_ID=b.Status_ID)
    left outer join Supervisor as c on (a.Requested_Login=c.Emp_Login)
    left outer join req_doc as d on (a.Req_ID=d.req_id)
    join Req_Part e on (a.Req_ID=e.Req_ID)
  where
    ((@datesearch is null or @datesearch=0) or (a.Req_Date between @startdate and @enddate))
    and ((@status_id is null or @status_id=0) or (a.Status_ID=@status_id))
    and ((@Vendor_Name is null or LEN(RTrim(@Vendor_Name))=0) or (a.Vendor_Name like '%'+@Vendor_Name+'%'))
    and ((@PO_Number is null or LEN(RTrim(@PO_Number))=0) or (a.PO_Number like @PO_Number+'%'))
    and ((@Req_ID is null or @Req_ID=0) or (a.Req_ID=@Req_ID))
    and ((@Part_ID is null or LEN(RTrim(@Part_ID))=0) or (e.Part_ID like '%'+@Part_ID+'%'))
END
```

### What is the best way to get this to stop returning the duplicate rows?

And, as a FYI: I did not design this database! I am aware of the fact that the column name `Requested_Buy` would be correctly spelled as `Requested_By`, but the database is already in production. Misspelled words really irritate me!

Comment: What do you need to return from `Req_Part`, at this moment your modified SP doesn't return anything from that table.

Comment: I don't need to return `Req_Part` - I only need the *Requests* that would contain those parts if the *Part Number* is supplied.

Comment: so you don't need to `INNER JOIN` just check `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ... ` in the where.

Comment: You are not getting duplicates per-se, for every part that request have you are getting a row/record. And thats because of the join

Comment: You are correct, Jafar. I need someone to write a `select distinct` statement so that I can accept their answer. A coworker has already shown me that is how to get my modified stored procedure to work.

Comment: @jp2code, I wouldn't use SELECT DISTINCT, even it works in here. As Luis LL suggested, if you don't need return anything from this table. another JOIN and SELECT DISTINCT will be unnecessary and may cause perforamance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you may update query like this.

```
  select
    a.Req_ID, a.Vendor_ID, a.Vendor_Name, a.Req_Date, a.PO_Number, a.Requested_Buy, a.approved,
    b.status,
    c.supervisor_login,
    case when d.req_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as HasDocs
  from Req as a
    join Status as b on (a.Status_ID=b.Status_ID)
    left outer join Supervisor as c on (a.Requested_Login=c.Emp_Login)
    left outer join req_doc as d on (a.Req_ID=d.req_id)
  where
    ((@datesearch is null or @datesearch=0) or (a.Req_Date between @startdate and @enddate))
    and ((@status_id is null or @status_id=0) or (a.Status_ID=@status_id))
    and ((@Vendor_Name is null or LEN(RTrim(@Vendor_Name))=0) or (a.Vendor_Name like '%'+@Vendor_Name+'%'))
    and ((@PO_Number is null or LEN(RTrim(@PO_Number))=0) or (a.PO_Number like @PO_Number+'%'))
    and ((@Req_ID is null or @Req_ID=0) or (a.Req_ID=@Req_ID))
    and ( ISNULL(@Part_ID,0) = 0 
            OR 
          EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Req_Part e WHERE a.Req_ID=e.Req_ID AND e.Part_ID like '%'+@Part_ID+'%')
        )
```

Comment: That might do it, Eric.

Comment: Somehow, this version is pulling up a `Request` that has no corresponding `Part Number` field to it. Is that because of the `ISNULL` function? If so, I'll need to remove it.

Comment: What does it mean to call **EXISTS** on **(SELECT NULL ...)**? Is that `NULL` Exists?

Comment: @jp2code, you can select anything in EXISTS, personally, I use SELECT NULL, you can replace it with SELECT 1 or SELECT * . There are no difference. For ISNULL part, I updated my answer, it should works now.